# Return one or two objects with getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

My component receives `profile` and `errors` from the parent. Within the component `static getDerivedStateFromProps` sets the new state should the component receive new data from the parent.

```
...
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            displaySocialInputs: false,
            handle: '',
            company: '',
            website: '',
            location: '',
            status: '',
            skills: '',
            githubusername: '',
            bio: '',
            twitter: '',
            facebook: '',
            linkedin: '',
            youtube: '',
            instagram: '',
            errors: {}
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
...

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.errors) {
            console.log('nextProps.errors:', nextProps.errors);
            return { errors: nextProps.errors };
        }

        if (nextProps.profile.profile) {
            const profile = nextProps.profile.profile;

            // bring skills array back to csv
            const skillsCsv = profile.skills.join(',');

            // if a profile field wasn't provided set it to an empty string
            profile.company = !isEmpty(profile.company) ? profile.company : '';
            profile.website = !isEmpty(profile.website) ? profile.website : '';
            profile.location = !isEmpty(profile.location) ? profile.location : '';
            profile.githubusername = !isEmpty(profile.githubusername) ? profile.githubusername : '';
            profile.bio = !isEmpty(profile.bio) ? profile.bio : '';
            profile.social = !isEmpty(profile.social) ? profile.social : {};
            profile.twitter = !isEmpty(profile.social.twitter) ? profile.social.twitter : '';
            profile.facebook = !isEmpty(profile.social.facebook) ? profile.social.facebook : '';
            profile.linkedin = !isEmpty(profile.social.linkedin) ? profile.social.linkedin : '';
            profile.youtube = !isEmpty(profile.social.youtube) ? profile.social.youtube : '';
            profile.instagram = !isEmpty(profile.social.instagram) ? profile.social.instagram : '';

            // set component state
            return {
                handle: profile.handle,
                company: profile.company,
                website: profile.website,
                location: profile.location,
                status: profile.status,
                skills: skillsCsv,
                githubusername: profile.githubusername,
                bio: profile.bio,
                twitter: profile.twitter,
                facebook: profile.facebook,
                linkedin: profile.linkedin,
                youtube: profile.youtube,
                instagram: profile.instagram
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The code above prevents the `profile` object from displaying on the page. When the

```
if (nextProps.errors) {
            console.log('nextProps.errors:', nextProps.errors);
            return { errors: nextProps.errors };
        }
```

part is commented out the `profile` data displays Ok but the `errors` data cannot display.

How do I get both `errors` and `profile` object to display? On my component submit the component field data submits to the parent so if all the required fields are not empty there should be no `errors` coming in.

The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/DevConnector/blob/master/client/src/components/common/ProfileForm.js

**UPDATE 1**

The parent component `EditProfile`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ProfileForm from '../common/ProfileForm';
import { createProfile, getCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profileActions';

class EditProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getCurrentProfile();
    }

    onSubmit(profileData) {
        this.props.createProfile(profileData, this.props.history);
    }

    render() {
        return <ProfileForm profile={this.props.profile} errors={this.props.errors} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
    }
}

EditProfile.propTypes = {
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    profile: state.profile,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProfile, getCurrentProfile })(withRouter(EditProfile));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return both the data, create an object first then add the key-values in respective `if` conditions and finally return that object. By that way it will execute both `if` conditions.

Like this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {

    let obj = {};

    if (nextProps.errors) {
        obj.errors = nextProps.errors;
    }

    if (nextProps.profile.profile) {
        const profile = nextProps.profile.profile;

        // bring skills array back to csv
        const skillsCsv = profile.skills.join(',');

        // if a profile field wasn't provided set it to an empty string
        profile.company = !isEmpty(profile.company) ? profile.company : '';
        profile.website = !isEmpty(profile.website) ? profile.website : '';
        profile.location = !isEmpty(profile.location) ? profile.location : '';
        profile.githubusername = !isEmpty(profile.githubusername) ? profile.githubusername : '';
        profile.bio = !isEmpty(profile.bio) ? profile.bio : '';
        profile.social = !isEmpty(profile.social) ? profile.social : {};
        profile.twitter = !isEmpty(profile.social.twitter) ? profile.social.twitter : '';
        profile.facebook = !isEmpty(profile.social.facebook) ? profile.social.facebook : '';
        profile.linkedin = !isEmpty(profile.social.linkedin) ? profile.social.linkedin : '';
        profile.youtube = !isEmpty(profile.social.youtube) ? profile.social.youtube : '';
        profile.instagram = !isEmpty(profile.social.instagram) ? profile.social.instagram : '';

        // set component state
        const temp = {
            handle: profile.handle,
            company: profile.company,
            website: profile.website,
            location: profile.location,
            status: profile.status,
            skills: skillsCsv,
            githubusername: profile.githubusername,
            bio: profile.bio,
            twitter: profile.twitter,
            facebook: profile.facebook,
            linkedin: profile.linkedin,
            youtube: profile.youtube,
            instagram: profile.instagram
        };

        obj = { ...obj, ...temp };
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: There is no `obj` property on the component state. All the individual fields are set to the state. Please see the edit.

Comment: obj is an object that will be merged with state object, `const obj={}; return obj;` and `return {};` is same, just different ways of writing :)

Comment: ultimately we need to return an object with key-value pairs, keys we want to update in state. try that code let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: It seems to work Ok. Another thing: how do I get rid of the `errors` object when visiting another p[age then returning to the component page? The field error still displays.

Comment: add one more condition as `else if (!nextProps.errors) {
        obj.errors = '';
    }` it will remove the errors, if errors is an object then assign the empty object :)

Comment: Here it's more complicated. The `errors` object (not a String) comes from the parent so the parent will still send it to the child `ProfileForm` component.